# how to prevent position goes top after adding items into listview, and notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, listview

```
    messages.addAll(0,lstLoadedTop10);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

the problem is.

after I add items into listview and doing notifyDataSetChanged();

the scrollbar goes top.

but I want to watch items on screen continuously.

for example. at the twitter app,  the position doesn't goes up after loading more twit.

sorry about my poor English.  thanks in advance.

Comment: did you ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) , it will be easy.

Try this: `scrollTo(int x, int y)`. Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29)

Good Luck